# Can we assume that this separation is formed of connected sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $Y$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we want to prove that $Y$ is connected. By contradiction we assume this is not the case, and so there are sets $A$ and $B$ such that $Y=A\cup B$ and the closure of each set does not interset the other set. My question is: can we ASSUME that $A$ and $B$ are connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other two  answers are indeed conclusive but the OP's resistance to accepting any one of them makes me suspect  that
they indeed want something slightly different, namely what one gets upon replacing
"$Y=A\cup B$" by "$Y\subseteq A\cup B$", in the statement of the question,  requiring also that both $A\cap Y$ and $B\cap Y$ are nonempty.

To be 100% precise here is my interpretation of the question:

**Question**.  Given a disconnected subset $Y⊆\mathbb R^n$, can one find open **connected** subsets $A,B ⊆\mathbb R^n$,
such that both $A\cap Y$ and $B\cap Y$ are nonempty, and $Y\subseteq A\cup B$?

In case $Y$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^1$, this is  indeed possible  since a disconnected subset $Y\subseteq \mathbb R$ cannot
be an
interval,  so there are points $y_1<x<y_2$, with $y_1,y_2\in Y$, and $x\notin Y$, and then  one may take
$A=(-\infty ,x)$ and   $B=(x, +\infty )$.

In higher dimensions I believe this is a very interesting and challenging problem, to which I have no answer.
Nevertheless,  in case $Y$ is compact, this is not so difficult,  and here is my attempt at proving it:

Given that $Y$ is disconnected, choose open subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb R^n$, with $Y\subseteq A\cup B$,  and   $A\cap Y\neq \emptyset\neq B\cap Y$.

For each point $y\in A\cap Y$,  let us choose an open *cube* $C_y$ such that $y\in C_y\subseteq A$.  Since the $C_y$ cover the compact set
$A\cap Y$,  we may find $y_1,\ldots ,y_n$ such that
$$
  A\cap Y\subseteq A':=\bigcup_{i=1}^nC_y \subseteq A.
  $$
Doing the same  relative to $B\cap Y$ we may find a finite union of open cubes $B'$ such that
$B\cap Y\subseteq B'\subseteq B$.

This said we may assume WLOG that the originally chosen sets $A$ and $B$  are each a finite union of open cubes.

Denoting by $A_1, A_2, \ldots ,  A_n$ the connected components of $A$,  each of which is obviously again a finite union of open
cubes,  we then have that $Y\cap A\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^nA_n$.

Doing the same with $B$,  and relabling
$$
 (C_1, C_2, \ldots ,  C_p):=  (A_1, A_2, \ldots ,  A_n; B_1,  B_2,  \ldots ,  B_m),
  $$
we see that

- each $C_i$ is a *connected* finite union of open cubes,
- $Y\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^pC_i$.

If  we discard the $C_i$ having no intersection with $Y$, we may also assume that

- $C_i\cap Y\neq \emptyset$, for all $i$,
- $p\geq 2$.

To conclude we must show how to  arrange a situation in which $p$ is exactly equal to 2.  For this assume that $p$ is
minimal and, by contradiction, that $p>2$.

The final part of the argument might be a bit awkward  to describe in detail,  but intuitively  it is pretty obvious:  clearly
one may find two such sets,  say $C_i$ and $C_j$,  and a bridge between them formed by a finite union of open cubes, without
going over any one of the remaining cubes.

One may then replace $C_i$ and $C_j$ by the single connected set formed by the
union of $C_i$,  $C_j$,  and the bridge,  hence reducing $p$ by 1 and contradicting minimality!

Answer (score 2):

No, certainly not. Take $n=1,$ $Y=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $A= \{1,2\}, B= \{3,4\}.$

Answer (score 1):

No, consider the space $Y := (0,1) \cup (2,3) \cup (4,5) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. This space is disconnected since there exists closed sets $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ and $(4,5)$ whose union is the whole space and whose intersection is empty. But one of the two is not connected.

Comment: I know that this is not correct in general. I am saying if we can ASSUME that by repeating the same argument to each connected set or...